# Unit testing bottle py application that uses request body results in KeyError: 'wsgi.input'

Tags: python, unit-testing, bottle

When unit testing a bottle py route function:

```
from bottle import request, run, post
@post("/blah/<boo>")
def blah(boo):
    body = request.body.readline()
    return "body is %s" % body
blah("booooo!")
```

The following exception is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in blah
  File "bottle.py", line 1197, in body
    self._body.seek(0)
  File "bottle.py", line 166, in __get__
    if key not in storage: storage[key] = self.getter(obj)
  File "bottle.py", line 1164, in _body
    read_func = self.environ['wsgi.input'].read
KeyError: 'wsgi.input'
```

The code will work if running as a server via bottle's `run` function, it's purely when I call it as a normal Python function e.g. in a unit test.

What am I missing? How can I invoke this as a normal python func inside a unit test?

Comment: I have raised this as an issue on bottle.py's Github project: https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/727

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually worked out what the problem is. I needed to "fake" the request environment for bottle to play nicely:

```
from bottle import request, run, post, tob
from io import BytesIO
body = "abc"
request.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = str(len(tob(body)))
request.environ['wsgi.input'] = BytesIO()
request.environ['wsgi.input'].write(tob(body))
request.environ['wsgi.input'].seek(0)
# Now call your route function and assert
```

Comment: nice! this is really helpful since the sample tests only cover the simple stuff. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: my lib does this exact faking for you: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boddle
just syntactic sugar of course.

Answer (score 2):

Another issue is that Bottle uses thread locals and reads the `BytesIO` object you put into `request.environ` the first time you access the `body` property on `request`. Therefore if you run multiple tests with post data, e.g. in a `TestCase`, when you come to read it in your request callback it will only return the value it was initially given, not your updated value.

The solution is to scrub all the values stored on the request object before each test, so in your `setUp(self)` you can do something like this:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp():
        # Flush any cached values
        request.bind({})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boddle.  In your test you could do:

```
from bottle import request, run, post
from boddle import boddle
@post("/blah/<boo>")
def blah(boo):
    body = request.body.readline()
    return "body is %s" % body

with boddle(body='woot'):
    print blah("booooo!")
```

Which would print `body is woot`.

Disclaimer: I authored.  (Wrote it for work.)